# In Expedition:Rome - Is there an option to respec?

Tags: expeditions-rome

In Expedition: Rome, is there a way to respec any of the characters or are skill/class choices permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally checked the Codex, and unless I learn there is an exception the rule seems to be no re-spec options.

[image]